# Python extract number between two special character in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I try to extract the number between the **$** and **white space** in a column, then use the number to create a new column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'name':['The car is selling at $15 dollars','he chair is selling at $20 dollars']})
```

I look at many solutions on stackoverflow about Regular expression. it's hard to understand

my code doesn't work

```
df['money'] = df['name'].str.extract(r'$\s*([^\.]*)\s*\.')
```

are there any other solutions besides RegEx, if not, how to fix my code?

Comment: I can explain why your regex doesn't work.  You have a dollar sign, then optional white space, then anything that is not a period, then optional white space, then a required period.  You never mentioned periods, and there are none in your sample data.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you explain why this answer work? df["money"] = df["name"].str.extract(r"\$(\d+\.?\d*)") thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the `$`:

```py
df["money"] = df["name"].str.extract(r"\$(\d+\.?\d*)")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                 name money
0   The car is selling at $15 dollars    15
1  he chair is selling at $20 dollars    20
```